# Assign createElement to variable in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file-upload, ecmascript-6

I am new to React and would like to use my method (works fine in plain js). I have got a problem with assigning createElement to variable.

```
class UploadBar extends Component {
  state = {
    selectedFile: null
  };

  fileSelectedHandler = event => {
    this.setState({
      selectedFile: event.target.files[0]
    });
  };

  fileLocalHandler = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    let link = URL.createObjectURL(this.selectedFile);
    let link = document.createElement("a");
    link.href = URL.createObjectURL(this.selectedFile);
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.download = this.selectedFile.name;
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="uploadBar">
        <input
          multiple
          type="file"
          accept="application/pdf"
          onChange={this.fileSelectedHandler}
        />
        <button id="uploadBtn" onClick={this.fileLocalHandler}>
          Upload a file
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Could you help me with proper use of my fileLocalHandler method?

Comment: What is the error reported?

Comment: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': No function was found that matched the signature provided.

Comment: Also this `this.selectedFile.name` should be `this.state.selectedFile.name`

Comment: Correct, thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to access the selected file from `this.state`, not directly from `this`:

```
fileLocalHandler = event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const { selectedFile } = this.state;
    let link = document.createElement("a");

    link.href = URL.createObjectURL(selectedFile);
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.download = selectedFile.name;
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
};
```